# angular 2- read propertyfile which is in tomcat

Tags: angular, file, tomcat, properties, config

I have angular 2 app, which querys the backend, running in tomcat server.
Now I want angular 2 app to read .properties file which resides in CATALINA_HOME.
and then use that server to query via service

angualr 2--> read config.propertis (apiURL) --> then it will call taht api URL

I have multiple customer, based on user input--> it will get value of apiURL to query that customer's backend.

Appreciate any help/ideas on this?
Jagruti Frank

Comment: The only solution is for your backend to get the file, and send it via an endpoint to Angular. Angular can't magically have knowledge of this file, so it's not Angular related (unless you don't know how to make an HTTP call)

Comment: angular2 and back end app both are in apache tomcat

Comment: And you want to do that in production mode ?

Comment: yes, based on input it will go and get the data from different api's

Comment: there is one front end, with multiple back end

Comment: Then Angular shouldn't read the file, if it's based on an input, right ?

Comment: different backend hosted on different machine

Comment: you can take the example of compare.com ( it fetches data from different customer/client )

Comment: In that case, instead of reading a file, you should use the `environment.ts` files that Angular CLI has created for you. In it, create an array of endpoint like this `let apis=['http://api1.com', 'http://api2.com'];` and so on. Now, if you want to make several api calls, either use a loop, or a condition !

Comment: any suggesstion to get apiURL populated?? config files which is not in angualr so that I dont change it with every new customer being added

Comment: Register it in a referential in your database ?

Comment: Case which I am worried is if new customer gets added, I need to change the environment.ts and build and redeploy. please correct me incase I am wrong

Comment: No you're right. You will have to redo the file. And you can't registrer all your endpoints in your database ?

Comment: that was another option I was thinking of,and exploring another possibilities

Comment: looking for simpler option so that helpdesk can do the required, and developer's time can be saved.

Comment: Well, Angular is JS and is executed on the client side, and once built, I really don't see how you can access server files ...

Comment: yes, that is the problem I am facing

Comment: thanks trichetriche, I think I am looking for something which is not possible

Comment: I can add end point in my backend which can provide list of customer and their endpoint

Comment: I think it would be the best solution yes ...